# How to prove $U = \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $V = \mathbb{R} -\mathbb{Q}$ be the set of all irrational numbers, $U$ is an open set of $\mathbb{R}$ and $V \subset U$.

Can $U = \mathbb{R}$ be proved?

Comment: I tried to use that the open set of $\mathbb{R}$ can be expressed as the union of open intervals.

Comment: If $U$ is connected, then it is true.

Answer (score 4):

Not true.
$$
V\subset \mathbb R\setminus\{0\}=U
$$
Clearly, $U$ is open!

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm shorted for a moment.

Answer (score 4):

For a counterexample take $U$ to be the complement of $\{0\}$.

Comment: I don't think you can just choose $U$ like that.

Comment: What do you mean? This $U$ is open, it contains $V$ but it is not equal to $\mathbb R$. So it is a valid counterexample.

Comment: Of course, I misread. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

No.  V subset open (-$\infty$,0) $\cup$ (0,$\infty$).